# Puppeteer + Pixelmatch: Comparing screenshots in Mac and TravisCI Linux

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to implement JS testing by loading pages and taking screenshots of the elements with puppeteer. So far so good, everything works perfectly in my local (after I fixed a snag between a normal screen an a retina display) but when I ran the same testing on TravisCI I got small text differences that I can't get around, anyone has any clue what is going on?

This is how I configure my browser instance:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch(({
        headless: true,
        args :[
          '--hide-scrollbars',
          '--enable-font-antialiasing',
          '--force-device-scale-factor=1', '--high-dpi-support=1',
          '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', // Props for TravisCI
        ]
      }));
```

And here is how I compare the screenshots:

```
const compareScreenshots = (fileName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const base = fs.createReadStream(`${BASE_IMAGES_PATH}/${fileName}.png`).pipe(new PNG()).on('parsed', doneReading);
    const live = fs.createReadStream(`${WORKING_IMAGES_PATH}/${fileName}.png`).pipe(new PNG()).on('parsed', doneReading);

    let filesRead = 0;
    function doneReading() {
      // Wait until both files are read.
      if (++filesRead < 2) {
        return;
      }

      // Do the visual diff.
      const diff = new PNG({width: base.width, height: base.height});
      const mismatchedPixels = pixelmatch(
          base.data, live.data, diff.data, base.width, base.height,
          {threshold: 0.1});

        resolve({
          mismatchedPixels,
          diff,
        });
    }
  });
};
```

Here is an example of the diff that this is generating:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I put in a delay of 400ms before snapping the screenshot and it seems to have fixed the problem. If you come up with something better I'd love to know it.

Comment: Any idea why that solved the problem? I had a different problem where the animations were still running but I fixed that one by speeding them up
`
await page._client.send('Animation.setPlaybackRate', { playbackRate: 12 });
`

Comment: My guess is that things are still jiggling around when puppeteer thinks it is ready to take the snapshot. I came to this guess when I saw some jiggling while manually resizing a window.

Comment: Interesting, I will let you know and report back

Comment: I wonder if the jiggling is due to CSS transitions. One tiny quick transition somewhere higher up on the page could do it. I have a button at the top of the page that transitions to be smaller at a certain breakpoint. I think that is what was causing my problem.

Comment: I don't think so, that is why I added  `await page._client.send('Animation.setPlaybackRate', { playbackRate: 12 });`

Answer (score 0):

Fonts can be rendered slightly differently on different OSes. This can cause the artifacts along the edges of the text that you are experiencing. You have a few options:

- apply a slight Gaussian blur to the images before comparison (or use css blur). This will smooth away the differences between hard edges in the images.
- increase the 'threshold' property to make the anti-aliasing filtering less sensitive.
- allow a certain number of pixel differences in your comparison by using a percentage of the total image ( width * height * percentage_threshold ). This number will be influenced by how much text is on the screen at any given point.
- use standardized Webfonts for all text - this could help get the fonts close to identical given that you are using the same browser on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I ended up with running my snapshot tests "locally" inside a docker container. I also mounted the project folder so whenever snapshots had to be updated they were updated inside the container but also in the host os.